# Why I cant get to hidden article by putting url with hashname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have been looking for solution, but i don't find anything, that would suit me. I got a page with header and content divs. Content `div` is not visible. After clicking on item in `nav menu`, I want to hide header, and show chosen article. I achieved it, but when I try to get to article by url#name nothing happens.

"jsfiddle" wont be useful in this case, but i will paste it to show my code.
Is there different way to do it? Maybe somehow hide articles with code, then just change opacity, maybe use "addclass" from jquery? I don't really know, im mixed and stuck.

Thanks for help.

https://jsfiddle.net/edby86ta/8/

Comment: You'll have to show some code which shows what you've tried to do when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply very simple JS conditions to show and hide your articles based on the link, I`ve updated you JSfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/edby86ta/10/

```js
$(function () {

    //GET HASH FROM URL, CHECK IF ELEMENT EXISTS AND THEN SHOW IT
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var hash = window.location.hash;
      if(hash.length){
       $(hash).show();
      }
    })
    
    $(".article-nav a").on("click", function () {       
        
        $(".main-article").hide();
        
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
         
        $('#article-' + $(this).attr("id")).show();
     });
});
```

```css
article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="article-nav">
      <li><a id="1" href="#article-1">Article 01</a></li>
      <li><a id="2" href="#article-2">Article 02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="content">
  <article id="article-1" class="main-article">Article 01 Lorem ipsum</article>
  <article id="article-2" class="main-article">Article 02 Lorem ipsum</article>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Advice: Be aware that the user can change the hash as he wants, injecting anything to your selector, you should check the hash before using it.

Comment: My problem is when i try to get to article by url e.g: xyz.zx/index.html#article then nothing happens, article is still hidden. Thanks for nice answer. Your code is much nicer than mine, i still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Alright, you can achive it by using `window.location.hash;`. See my updated question...

Comment: My god its so simple! Thanks  you a lot

Comment: This part of code doesn't work for me:
console.log($(this).attr("id"));
$('#article-' + $(this).attr("id")).show();  
After i put $("#article-1").show(); after  "$(".article-nav a").on("click", function () { " line, it works showing article-1 after clicking on <a> element.

Comment: When instead of  $('#' +$(this).attr("id")).show(); i put  $($(this).attr("id")).show(); ,and for id of a element i set #art1 instead of art1, it works. I don't know why, and what could be wrong with summing '#' and $(this).attr("id").

Comment: In jQuery selectors, `#` is to get a element by the `ID`, and `.` for element `classes`, see docs: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). Element IDs should be unique within the entire document, I believe you are duplicating the IDs setting it as `#art1` for both articles and it links... You can also use the attribute `data` like: `<li><a data-article="art1" href="#art1">Article 01</a></li>` and `<article id="art1"...`, and then replace the jQuery with: `$('#' + $(this).data("article")).show();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in full css :
https://jsfiddle.net/edby86ta/11/

In this case, the hardest part is hiding it again. You'd have to have a "close" button directing to another (maybe nonexistant) anchor :

```
<a href="#clear">Close</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. As you said, i got close button, that allows me to get back. My problem is, when i use display:none for items, i cant call them by url with hash. I wonder if there is any option to hide element, and make it not preserve space, but still be able to be called. I could use absolute positioning of article to make it not break document by preserving space. I bet there are so many options i dont see yet.
I will try to use javscript to make it possible calling it by hash.